# How to rearrange text file in certain order?

Tags: matlab, sorting, text

I have big data as text file(table is 3,496,080 rows x 6 columns) and would like to rearrange it? I looked at sort function but I didn't make no progress. I used `sort` function via toolstrip in MATLAB and nearly got data what I want. I tried to use `writetable` function but I got error as follows:

```
Error using writetable
Too many output arguments.
```

How should I use sort function and then write a text file?

```
 data = sortrows(ionex, {'Year','DoY','Hour','Lat','Long','TEC'},'ascend');
```

For example:

```
1998 152 1 30 30 12
1998 152 1 30 25 12.5
1998 152 1 30 35 11.8
1998 152 1 30 40 11.9
1998 152 1 30 45 12
1998 152 3 30 25 10.9
1998 152 3 30 30 10.7
1998 152 3 30 35 10.6
1998 152 3 30 40 10.5
1998 152 3 30 45 10.4
1998 152 5 30 25 9.6
1998 152 5 30 30 9.5
1998 152 5 30 35 9.2
1998 152 5 30 40 9
1998 152 5 30 45 8.7
1998 152 7 30 25 8.4
1998 152 7 30 30 8.5
1998 152 7 30 35 8.9
1998 152 7 30 40 9.6
1998 152 7 30 45 10.7
1998 152 9 30 25 13.2
1998 152 9 30 30 14.3
1998 152 9 30 35 15.2
1998 152 9 30 40 15.9
1998 152 9 30 45 16.2
1998 152 11 30 25 16.2
1998 152 11 30 30 16.5
1998 152 11 30 35 16.8
1998 152 11 30 40 17.2
1998 152 11 30 45 17.9
1998 152 13 30 25 18
1998 152 13 30 30 18.6
1998 152 13 30 35 19.3
1998 152 13 30 40 20.1
1998 152 13 30 45 21.2
1998 152 15 30 25 20.4
1998 152 15 30 30 21.4
1998 152 15 30 35 22.5
1998 152 15 30 40 23.7
1998 152 15 30 45 25
1998 152 17 30 25 21.8
1998 152 17 30 30 23.2
1998 152 17 30 35 24.7
1998 152 17 30 40 26
1998 152 17 30 45 26.9
1998 152 19 30 25 22.4
1998 152 19 30 30 23.4
1998 152 19 30 35 24.3
1998 152 19 30 40 25
1998 152 19 30 45 25.6
1998 152 21 30 25 25.1
1998 152 21 30 30 25
1998 152 21 30 35 24.3
1998 152 21 30 40 23.3
1998 152 21 30 45 22
1998 152 23 30 25 20.9
1998 152 23 30 30 19
1998 152 23 30 35 17.2
1998 152 23 30 40 15.7
1998 152 23 30 45 14.5
```

Sort_data

```
1998 152 1 30 25 12.5
1998 152 1 30 30 12
1998 152 1 30 35 11.8
1998 152 1 30 40 11.9
1998 152 1 30 45 12
1998 152 1 32.5 25 11.6
1998 152 1 32.5 30 11.1
1998 152 1 32.5 35 10.9
1998 152 1 32.5 40 11
1998 152 1 32.5 45 11.3
1998 152 1 35 25 10.7
1998 152 1 35 30 10.2
1998 152 1 35 35 10
1998 152 1 35 40 10.1
1998 152 1 35 45 10.5
1998 152 1 37.5 25 10.1
1998 152 1 37.5 30 9.5
1998 152 1 37.5 35 9.2
1998 152 1 37.5 40 9.3
1998 152 1 37.5 45 9.6
1998 152 1 40 25 9.6
1998 152 1 40 30 8.9
1998 152 1 40 35 8.6
1998 152 1 40 40 8.5
1998 152 1 40 45 8.8
1998 152 1 42.5 25 9.3
1998 152 1 42.5 30 8.6
1998 152 1 42.5 35 8.2
1998 152 1 42.5 40 8
1998 152 1 42.5 45 8.1
1998 152 1 45 25 9.3
1998 152 1 45 30 8.6
1998 152 1 45 35 8.2
1998 152 1 45 40 8
1998 152 1 45 45 8.1
1998 152 3 30 25 10.9
1998 152 3 30 30 10.7
1998 152 3 30 35 10.6
1998 152 3 30 40 10.5
1998 152 3 30 45 10.4
1998 152 3 32.5 25 10.2
1998 152 3 32.5 30 10
1998 152 3 32.5 35 9.9
1998 152 3 32.5 40 9.9
1998 152 3 32.5 45 10
```

Comment: Don't disturb the format as the input was. Keep it in the same format....if you have cells use fprintf. More help based on how your input is.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] including a **small** sample data set, how you want the data rearranged, and your current attempt at sorting.